# How to use form field only as value in controller method with a corresponding column in the db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following simple form in a view:

```
<%= form_for(@invitation, method: :post, url: addinvitation_path) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <label for="email", title="email"></label>
  <%= f.email_field :email, required: true %><br>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Having added this form to a view, tests that use this view fail:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `email' for #<Invitation:0x0000000baa4e88>
```

`email` is not a variable in the Invitation table, am I correct to assume that is the cause of the error? All I want is for the email field/value to be available in the controller method (where I will use it to find the right user). How can I do this? 
*(at first sight it might look to make more sense to then use `form_for(@user` since the `email` field of that table but I don't want that since I will use the form to write to the `Invitation` table)*

Comment: `<%= email_field_tag :email ... %>` would make `params[:email]` available to your controller.

Comment: It's looking like email field is not  available on the Invitation model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use form_for object ('f' in your case) with column names present in the table. As email is not a column in your invitation table so you need to use direct field_tag.

```
  <%= email_field_tag :email, required: true %
```